# How to have a function wait until an object's value is not undefined js setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, intervals

I need to stop a function from proceeding until my php script gets the contents from a file that takes a bit of time to load. Once loaded I update the object that holds this information on my JavaScript file: `var setData = seoApp.siteData.result.wordCount;`

I have created a function that updates my html elements based on the results of the `wordCount`.

I want my script to continually check if the var `setData` is not undefined every few seconds to wait for the script to load the setData. I thought I could do this with setTimeout using this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i);
      if(setData !== undefined){
        // stops the loop from running again
        i =  11
        //run if statements here.
      }else {

      }
    }, 6000);
  }
```

Well that didn't work. It waits a few seconds and then fires the for loop without waiting for six seconds until the next one.

What am I doing wrong and is this the best way to approach this?

As requested the php script to scrape the data:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET["url"];
$string = $_GET["keywords"];


  libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  $explodedContent = explode("<title>", $content);
  $explodedExplodedContent = explode("</title>", $explodedContent[1]);

  $explodedBody = explode("<body>", $content);
  $explodedExplodedBody = explode("</body>", $explodedBody[0]);

  echo "{ \"result\": ". "{ ";
  echo "\"titleCount\": " . substr_count($explodedExplodedContent[0], $string) . ", "; // title of that page.
  echo "\"bodyCount\": " . substr_count(strip_tags($explodedExplodedBody[0]), $string);
  echo " } }";
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the wrong approach. Instead use the ajax callback to do your actions. Please show the code where you make your request to the server (for it to do its PHP bit).

Comment: thanks for the input @trincot, as you will probably tell I'm neither a php or javascript expert :) but the php file just echoes the json data, I don't even know if this is the way I'm supposed to do it, but if the php script doesn't time out it works with my javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Is that PHP script the same script that contains your Javascript, or do you have two scripts, one for the page with the JavaScript, and another, separate script which outputs the file? If separate, can you show the code that triggers that second PHP script?

Comment: The index.html file only calls the javascript, I use a javascript function to access that script on my server using: new XMLHttpRequest()... So yeah, two seperate scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already use the callback function of your `XMLHttpRequest` object, in which you set `setData` to the JSON output that the PHP script has returned. That is also the place where you should initiate any further processing:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var setData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        process(setData);
    }
};

// ...

function process(setData) {
    // Here you can do what you need to do with `setData`
}
```

If you want to do something while the data has not yet been returned, then use `setInterval`:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
     console.log('still waiting...');
}, 6000);
```

... and clear that interval once you have your data. But that you can easily do based on the request that returns (which is nicer than checking whether `setData` is not `undefined`):

```
function process(setData) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    // Here you can do what you need to do with `setData`
}
```

The reason your code did not work was that your `for` loop created 10 time-outs all at the same time, which all expired together 6 seconds later. It would have worked if you would have named the function given to `setTimeout` and passed that one to a new `setTimeout` when the first timeout expires:

```
setTimeout(function repeatTimeout() {
    console.log(i);
    if(setData !== undefined){
        // stops the loop from running again
        i =  11
        //run if statements here.
    } else {
        setTimeout(repeatTimeout, 6000);
    }
}, 6000);
```

... but with `setInterval` combined with `clearInterval` it is more straightforward.

#### Addendum

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfycrpow/) has code based on the code you presented in a fiddle, with comments on where to make changes.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, this makes sense but I can't figure out how to use it with my code. I have created this fiddle with my code on it: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/nkemxpga/ I used a function that takes three params to do the xmlhttp step of getting the json, the three params: url, what data to update on my app object, and now the function I want to execute (clear interval). When it runs I get this error: toolbelt.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: func is not a function but then I get the expected results in my html file after a few seconds. Any ideas or should I start a new question

Comment: The problem in the fiddle is that you pass `seoApp.bodyCount` as third argument, which should be a function, but you define `seoApp.bodyCount` nowhere.

Comment: I added your fiddle with some corrections in my answer. I did not test it, but it should point in the right direction.